# Joining multiple strings if they are not empty in Python

Tags: python, string, join

I have four strings and any of them can be empty. I need to join them into one string with spaces between them. If I use:

```
new_string = string1 + ' ' + string2 + ' ' + string3 + ' ' + string4
```

The result is a blank space on the beginning of the new string if `string1` is empty. Also, I have three blank spaces if `string2` and `string3` are empty.

How can I easily join them without blank spaces when I don't need them?

Answer (score 301, accepted):

```
>>> strings = ['foo','','bar','moo']
>>> ' '.join(filter(None, strings))
'foo bar moo'
```

By using `None` in the [`filter()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#filter) call, it removes all falsy elements.

Comment: How can this solution be applied when applying this to a column of a dataframe. When you are trying `df.apply(", ".join(filter(None, ...)), axis=1)`. How does one pass the second argument of the filter function?

Comment: @Michael, try `", ".join(filter(None, df.apply(a_function_call_without_brackets_which_iterates_over_rows_of_df_and_returns_some_second_argument, axis=1)))` - it was tested in my code and should work for you or anyone out there - as well

Answer (score 34):

If you KNOW that the strings have no leading/trailing whitespace:

```
>>> strings = ['foo','','bar','moo']
>>> ' '.join(x for x in strings if x)
'foo bar moo'
```

otherwise:

```
>>> strings = ['foo ','',' bar', ' ', 'moo']
>>> ' '.join(x.strip() for x in strings if x.strip())
'foo bar moo'
```

and if any of the strings have non-leading/trailing whitespace, you may need to work harder still. Please clarify what it is that you actually have.

Comment: Strings comes from the input text fields, so everything is possible. Thanks!

Answer (score -3):

```
strings = ['foo','','bar','moo']
' '.join([x for x in strings if x is not ''])
'foo bar moo'
```

Comment: Better use `!=` instead of `is not`. It might work, but it's not guaranteed to. Or just use `[x for x in strings if x]`.

Comment: **Never** use `is not` for non-singletons if you do not actually want to check if both are the same objects!